# Не следует ведь в подобных случаях ставить запятую перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Она злится на меня() как на мужчину.
Он презирает взяточничество() как часть русского жизнеуклада, а не само по себе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Он презирает взяточничество как часть русского жизненного уклада, а не само по себе.**

Здесь значение  "в качестве", и оно ясно обозначено **противопоставлением**. Запятая не ставится.

**2) Она злится на меня () как на мужчину.**

В предложении такой структуры **весьма вероятно отсутствие запятой,** но смысл здесь всё-таки неоднозначный, и поэтому желателен контекст.

**а) Значение в качестве** (запятая не ставится)

Она злится на меня как на мужчину (мужа, партнера), но ценит во мне стабильность и другие положительные качества.

**б) Значение причины** (запятая ставится)

Мужчины вообще во многих вопросах превосходят женщин, и она злится на меня, как на мужчину (так как я мужчина).

Comment: Ну тогда еще такой вариант.  Я женщина, а он злится на меня, как на мужчину. (Сравнение)

Comment: Злится, что не могу починить стиральную машину, плиту и холодильник?

Comment: Возможно и так, но я имел в виду, что некоторые капризы женщине прощают, а мужчине нет. Или что злость, направленная на женщину, выражается не так агрессивно.

Answer (score 2):

1. В первом примере решает *контекст*: если это говорит одна женщина о другой, то имеет место сравнение (злится, как злятся на мужчину), и запятая *нужна*; если говорит мужчина, то вероятнее всего, "её" не устраивают какие-либо качества, которые обычно требуют от мужчины (*в качестве* мужчины он стал объектом типичной критики), тогда запятая *не нужна*.
2. Во втором примере решает оговорка "**не само по себе**": *в качестве* уклада русской жизни взяточничество неуместно (но пусть себе процветает вне этого уклада). **Запятая не нужна**. Не будь этой оговорки, можно было бы (с "его" позиций) трактовать взяточничество как неотъемлемую часть русского уклада и рассматривать часть предложения, начинающуюся с "как", как уточняющую конструкцию со значением "а это, как известно, часть русского уклада". Поскольку такая трактовка факультативна (возможен и смысл исходного, полного предложения), то и постановка запятой была бы *факультативной* - в зависимости от придаваемого смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна.

> § 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях: ...б) при передаче значения «в качестве» (оборот является частью сказуемого): Сергей Лазо был прислан комитетом как главнокомандующий (Фад.); ...Тамара Ивановна поняла этот голос как посланное ей вдогонку прощание (Расп.); ([Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125))

Дополнение.

Отсутствие контекста — ловушка для отвечающего. Будучи представителем мужской половины человечества, я понял, что первую фразу произносит мужчина. Но возможен и такой вариант: "Я женщина, а онa злится на меня, как на мужчину". Тогда это сравнение и запятая нужна.